# Running jss cli commands from c# class

Tags: jss

Im trying to run jss cli commands (Windows Powershell) from my C# Class. I`m creating the commands dynamically, but i noticed that jss commands are not running.

```
            PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();

            //Call Powershell
            foreach (var item in scripts)
            {
                ps.AddScript(item);
            }
            Collection<PSObject> results = ps.Invoke();
```

This is the code to create the scripts dynamically:

```
             //Name of Component
             var nameofComponent = definitonArchive.Name.Replace(".sitecore.js", "");
             var locationSystem = Sitecore.Configuration.Settings.GetSetting("X:JSSApplicationFolder");

             //Add location command
             PowerShellCommands.Add($"Set-Location -Path {locationSystem}");

             //Create the JSS manifest command
             var jssManifestCommand = String.Format("jss manifest --manifestSourceFiles '{0}'", definitonArchive.FullName.Replace("/", @"\"));
             PowerShellCommands.Add($"Invoke-Expression \"{jssManifestCommand}\"");


             //Add build command
             var jssDeployCommand = "jss deploy app --includeContent --includeDictionary";
             PowerShellCommands.Add($"Invoke-Expression \"{jssDeployCommand}\"");
```

I noticed that nothing was happening, however using a console application with the same logic, everything works fine.

I created another command just to create a txt file, in purpose to test, and works fine.

```
              //To test
              PowerShellCommands.Add(@"New-Item C:\temp\test.txt");
```

I also created a log to check if the scripts are with a correct syntax, and they are good.

I noticed the error i`m receiving is:

**The term 'jss' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.**

Comment: How are you running the C# class?

Comment: @HishaamNamooya Web project. I call an API from my view using Ajax and my API call the Service that contains these logics.

Comment: I’m trying to replicate the issue but i cannot get passed by the powershell library. I mean i cannot see the system.management.automation assembly. Can please provide more details on this or share the nuget package

Comment: @HishaamNamooya I noticed that the error that I`m receiving is:

The term 'jss' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

Its weird because if I run the same command that I`m running but manually, works perfectly.

Comment: Is the jss command installed globally?

Comment: Yes, "JSS CLI is running in global mode because it was not installed in the local node_modules folder."

Comment: @FernandoC. did you find a fix?